# Jackson: remove some values from json and keep some null values

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a model like this:

```
public class Employee {
    @JsonProperty("emplyee_id")
    private Integer id;
    @JsonProperty("emplyee_first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @JsonProperty("emplyee_last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @JsonProperty("emplyee_address")
    private String address;
    @JsonProperty("emplyee_age")
    private Byte age;
    @JsonProperty("emplyee_level")
    private Byte level;

    //getters and setters
}
```

now I need to create two JSONs using this (only) model.

the first one must like this for example:

```
{
    "employee_id":101,
    "employee_first_name":"Alex",
    "employee_last_name":"Light",
    "employee_age":null,
    "employee_address":null
}
```

and the second one must like this for example:

```
{
    "employee_id":101,
    "employee_level":5
}
```

by the way, I already tested `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)`.

the problem of the first one (as much as I know) is, those fields can't be included in other JSONs (for example if `level` get this annotation, it won't be included in the second JSON)

and the problem of the second one is, `null` values can't be included in JSON.

so can I keep null values and prevent some other property to be included in JSON without creating extra models? if the answer is yes, so how can I do it? if it's not I really appreciate if anyone gives me the best solution for this state.

thanks very much.

Comment: use @JsonView(XXX.class)  annotations

Comment: @KalaiselvanA can I use a field in two JSONs with this annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it could be useful for you using @JsonView annotation

```
public class Views {
    public static class Public {
    }
    public static class Base {
    }
 }



public class Employee {
   @JsonProperty("emplyee_id")
   @JsonView({View.Public.class,View.Base.class})
   private Integer id;

   @JsonProperty("emplyee_first_name")
   @JsonView(View.Public.class)
   private String firstName;

   @JsonProperty("emplyee_last_name")
   @JsonView(View.Public.class)
   private String lastName;

   @JsonProperty("emplyee_address")
   private String address;

   @JsonProperty("emplyee_age")
   private Byte age;

   @JsonProperty("emplyee_level")
   @JsonView(View.Base.class)
   private Byte level;

   //getters and setters
 }
```

in your json response add @JsonView(Public/Base.class) it will return based on jsonview annotations

```
//requestmapping
@JsonView(View.Public.class)  
public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeWithPublicView(){
    //do something
}
```

response:

```
{ 
  "employee_id":101,
  "employee_first_name":"Alex",
  "employee_last_name":"Light",
  "employee_age":null,
  "employee_address":null
}
```

for the second one

```
//requestmapping
@JsonView(View.Base.class)  
public ResponseEntity<Employee> getEmployeeWithBaseView(){
    //do something
}
```

response

```
{
   "employee_id":101,
   "employee_level":5
}
```

Comment: I pretty sure it will work but let me check it first. thanks for your answer

Comment: I really really thanks for your solution. it works perfectly for my case. I just use interface for Views instead class