# Jackson JsonMappingException: Unrecognized column 'C': known columns {"A","B"}

Tags: java, json, csv

how do i create partial representation from myBean

class MyBean{
A,
B,
C
}

i would like to create csv only for A,B properties

using the following code throw the exception bellow

```
CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder().
                    .addColumn("A")
                    .addColumn("B")
                    .build();
```

CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(schema);

byte[] csv  = writer.writeValueAsBytes(bean);

getting the exception :

**JsonMappingException: Unrecognized column 'C': known columns {"A","B"}**

i'm using jackson 2.7.3

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring new fields on JSON objects using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455014/ignoring-new-fields-on-json-objects-using-jackson)

Comment: did you take a look at JsonView in Jackson? I had similar question a few days ago, I hope this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004348/jackson-remove-some-values-from-json-and-keep-some-null-values

Answer (score 9):

Configure CSV Mapper like this

```
 CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper(); 
 mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.IGNORE_UNKNOWN,true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Annotate your class with @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class MyBean{ A, B, C }
```